# How can I erase navbar lists with responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make the navbar disappear when >1170px and >820px but for some reason it doesn't work and i can't seem to find my mistake. I have tried different methods and solutions I found online but none worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/background-realistic-abstract-technology-particle_23-2148431735.jpg?w=900&t=st=1694459240~exp=1694459840~hmac=10beaeb0a700fb1bae3d92486cbbecf8cd8542f92e1651063157cb509665e0ee);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

a:hover {
    color: orange;
}

/*HEADER*/

header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar .logo a {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar .links {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
}

.navbar .toggle_btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.action_btn {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: scale 0.2 ease;
}

.action_btn:hover {
    scale: 1.05;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.action_btn:active {
    scale: 0.95;
}

/*DROPDOWN MENU*/

.dropdown_menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2rem;
    top: 60px;
    height: 0;
    width: 300px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.dropdown_menu.open {
    height: 240px;
}

.dropdown_menu li {
    padding: 0.7rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown_menu .action_btn {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

/*RESPONSIVE DESIGN*/

@media (max-width: 1170px) {
    .navbar .links,
    .navbar .action_btn {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar .toggle_btn {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown_menu {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 820px) {
    .dropdown_menu {
        left: 2rem;
        width: unset;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css">
    <title>Logistics</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo"><a href='#'>Logistics</a></div>
                <li><a href="hero">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="company">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="suppliers">Suppliers</a></li>
                <li><a href="calculation">Cost Calculation</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact">Contuct Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="customers">Customer List</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="action_btn">Get Started</a>
            <div class="toggle_btn">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown_menu">
            <li><a href="hero">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="company">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="suppliers">Suppliers</a></li>
            <li><a href="calculation">Cost Calculation</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact">Contuct Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="customers">Customer List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="action_btn">Get Started</a></li>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <script>
        const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('.toggle_btn')
        const toggleBtnIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle_btn i')
        const dropDownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown_menu')

        toggleBtn.onclick = function() {
            dropDownMenu.classList.toggle('open')
            const isOpen = dropDownMenu.classList.contains('open')
            toggleBtnIcon.classList = isOpen
            ? 'fa-solid fa-xmark'
            : 'fa-solid fa-bars'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For example when below 1170px I don't want the Home Company Suppliers etc to show. I only want the hamburer menu to function.

Comment: You have a selector for `.navbar .links` and perhaps you mean `.navbar li`?

Comment: No that doesn't solve the problem unfortunatelly.

Comment: First, your HTML is broken. You need to start the unordered list `<ul>` after the end div of `<div class="logo">`. Then in your CSS `change .navbar .links` to `.navbar ul`

Comment: I saw that i hadn't put <ul> after div after your comment but instead i got rid of the unordered list altogether and put istead .navbar li. That fixed my problem thank you.